# How to unwrap from project from view using marked seams?

Tags: texturing, uv, texture-coordinates

The question is in the title. I have a setup angle from where I wanna unwrap my object. But I wanna unwrap it using the premade seams I made earlier.

Also editing the seams in UV-editor is not an answer, because I have too many islands.

Comment: the seams are only used by the first unwrap option ("Unwrap"), if you want to unwrap Project From View, only select the part you want to unwrap this way.

Comment: It does not work. The reason why I need it by that way is that I need to have the faces and islands exactly in the same order. If they move even slightly, then the project will fail. Only way to have them by that order is project from view, but it does not allow me using seams.

Comment: perhaps give more details, a screenshot of your project so that someone can give you a solution?